# Inserting data from a database into a jTable in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm trying to put data from my database into a jTable and the program isn't throwing an error, but it does nothing. This is the method I'm using. Thanks for the help.

```
public void displayTable()
{
    try
    {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://TransactionTrackerDB.accdb");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String SQL = "SELECT transactionID, startDate, description, totalSum,"
                + " instalments, balanceDue FROM RecurringExpense ORDER BY transactionID DESC";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
        display.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(MonthlyExpensesClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: At this stage your best bet is to first do some debugging to see the state of your variables and the program flow as your program runs. Most all modern IDE's include a debugger, and so it should be easy to get started using it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `DefaultTableModel table`  poor name for it, BTW.  I'd instead use `DefaultTableModel tableModel` to avoid confusion between it and a `JTable table` instance.

Comment: your problem is not clear...please post your debugging findings, if you have done anything..Also do the proper exception handling in your code.

Comment: @douglas put a sout inside the loop and check does it loop at least one time.

Comment: I have a try catch, just not show here for exception handling. I tried a debug it comes up clean, so I really have no idea what the problem could even be.

Comment: @Fast Snail I added a sout and it is running, and runs the correct number of times.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable in its current form as you must first isolate the bug, or failing that, post your [mcve] as suggested by @AndrewThompson; please read the link for the details.

Answer (score 1):

To put data from  database into a jTable I always use user specified method such as below;

Note - I'm not including getting connection with the database codes. `list_table` is the table that you want to show database content.

```
    private void updateTable(){

        try {
            //getting data from the mysql database
            String sql = "SELECT transactionID, startDate, description, totalSum,"
                + " instalments, balanceDue FROM RecurringExpense ORDER BY transactionID DESC";
            PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
            list_table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

            // re sizing the column width
           list_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(15);
          //as this change getColumn(column number) and size the columns
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error : "+ex);
        }
}
```

Then call the defined `updateTable();` as you want to retrieve data from the database.